# My location button not appearing in view (Google maps SDK, ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios7

Here is my mapViewController.m file:

```
@interface MapViewController()

@property (strong, nonatomic) GMSMapView* mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *subView;

@end

@implementation MapViewController

    - (void) viewDidLoad{
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];

    _mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];

    _mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    _mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    _mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

    [self.subView addSubview:_mapView];
}
```

My problem is that the my location button doesn't appear, any help appreciated! :)
Please tell me if you need to see more of my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. Problem was that I added the mapview as a subview, and not to the outlet view. Now its fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Got the correct answer. This will work even if you added the mapview as a subview. Tested and verified the same upto IOS 9.2

```
_mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once, and to make it easier, I used CoreLocation that's built into Cocoa Touch to get the current location and then used those coordinates to add a marker to the Google Map, I hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like for the button to appear so the user can use it.