# "My location button" in google map disappeared

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, ios8

I'am trying to add a view to google map which both have been created using the storyboard. In order to do this, I've changed this part of the code:

```
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

to this:

```
  mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
  self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
 [self.view insertSubview:mapView atIndex:0];
```

it works, but the default "My location button" disappeared after this. Is there a way to get back the default button? I would greatly appreciate any help.

I tried this solution [My location button not appearing in view (Google maps SDK, ios)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24703229/2059029)
but it didn't work or maybe I didn't get it correctly, if this is the only solution could you please explain it in details?

Comment: Are you sure, mapView and self.mapView are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got around this problem by creating a button from the storyboard and connect it to this action.

```
- (IBAction)MyLocation:(id)sender {

CLLocation *location = mapView.myLocation;
if (location) {
    [mapView animateToLocation:location.coordinate];
}  }
```

In my case, if I place the created button on the lower right/left corner still can't get it but everywhere else is just fine. (I don't know why I think because of inserting the map at index 0 or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Are you requesting access to location services correctly? It's done a bit different in iOS 8. Try adding the following to you Info.plist file and let me know if it works:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to request location usage permission goes here</string>
```

Comment: I have done that already, I found a solution and I will post it as an answer.